# Quartz job going into Error state on adding a new job while some instance running with old code

Tags: .net, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net-2.0

I have implemented Scheduler quartz with .net and having an HA environment where multiple instances of scheduler are working. While upgrading my instances with a new code having new jobs created, the newly added job goes into ERROR state because of implementation of clustering, it sometimes fires on instance having old code.

Please help